# Products in PAAS environment

Tags: cloud, tibco, paas, cloud-foundry

We have Pivotal Cloud Foundry  and the apps are being migrated to cloud. The most Java based apps are easily getting migrated . But looks like PCF doesn't have Tibco for us to migrate our Tibco services. I am looking for various options to migrate our Tibco services into PCF.

Answer (score 1):

Business Works 6 comes with many deployment options : On-premise ("classic"), **Container** and "full" cloud (called Cloud Integration, separate but very similar IDE).

Their **container** option might be what you are looking for.

It is called : BusinessWorks Container Edition (BWCE)

Version 1.0 supports PCF.

The recently (last week) released version 2.0 of BWCE also support Docker and Google IaaS options.

The documentation is [here](https://docs.tibco.com/products/tibco-businessworks-container-edition-2-0-0).